# Can you use an OnClickListener with a toast?

Tags: android, android-toast

I want to show a toast - simple. The issue is I can't incorporate an OnClickListener for it. When I click on the toast I want to trigger an event.

Is it possible to use an OnClickListener with a toast?

Comment: What you want is a dialog. The sdk docs provide a good tutorial. You can make it look like a toast and register clicks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No you can't. But to achieve same like functionality, you may use Crouton library instead of Toasts.

https://github.com/keyboardsurfer/Crouton

Answer (score 2):

No! certainly Not! A toast provides simple feedback about an operation in a small popup.
If you want to get Click event consider using Dialog for it

Answer (score 1):

No you cant add listener to a `Toast` but you can create a custom view use it like `Toast` and  implement `onClickListener` on it.

Comment: you might want to use `snackbar` or use custom views for toasts and use it on Toast using `setView()`

Answer (score 1):

Toast also has getView() and setView() methods which enable you to set the custom view and still keep the Toast functionality.
You can set onClick listenet to your custom view